# Access Python Api Deployed On GCP Keubernetes through browser

Tags: python, api, kubernetes, deployment, google-cloud-platform

> I have deployed flask api on GCP kubernetes and I have ip address for the api . While I am accessing through terminal ,it giving me response. Now I am trying to access it using a python and using directly through browser but it is giving me nothing.What exactly process or python code which help me to connect my python code to kubernetes api.Thanks

Comment: please can you share how you are accessing it through terminal? What command you are running?

Comment: I am using this command "" curl -X POST -F image=@dog.jpg 'http://35.225.226.94/predict "" and its giving me output but when i try to same ip in browser it give me  "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: How actually use this ip address to get response in my browser or in my python program.Can you give me any helpful resource or anythhing else

Comment: I am using the method which is given in following link "" https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploy-your-first-deep-learning-model-on-kubernetes-with-python-keras-flask-and-docker-575dc07d9e76 ""

Comment: You probably need to create an HTML page which can select and post image to your URL. Please remove the IP address from your post for your security reasons.

Comment: Can you elaborate it please,I cannot get your point

Comment: Here is an example html code which you can use: https://codepen.io/rcass/pen/MmYwEp. Save it locally, change form action URLs accordingly, select file and post form

Comment: Actually I am deep learning developer,can you tell what mistake i am doing right now

Comment: can you send me a link of any resources which helpful for me to deploy python api

Comment: Did you try the curl from your machine or from an instance on the cluster?